# User control that opens dialog, where dialog result updates properties in viewmodel of the page that uses it

Tags: wpf, mvvm, controls

I have been struggling with this question for some time now. It seems relatively simple, but I am unsure of how to solve it. Would love your aid on this.

I have a page that's bound to viewmodel, that has some string properties that represent file paths.

I've built a user control that has a textbox and a button. The control's purpose: show a dialog when you click on the button(file dialog), and update the textbox according to the result.

Here is the xaml:

```
<UserControl x:Class="MyProject.Controls.FilePickerLauncherControl"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         x:Name="me"
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
<DockPanel>
    <Button Content="..." DockPanel.Dock="Right" Command="{Binding OpenFileDialogCommand,ElementName=me}"></Button>
    <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=PathChosen,ElementName=me}" DockPanel.Dock="Right" VerticalAlignment="Center" Height="30"></TextBox>
</DockPanel>
```

This is my the command in page's view model(the action):

```
    private void OpenFileExplorer()
    {
        SimpleIoc.Default.GetInstance<IInputOutputService>().OpenFileDialog(modelsDirectory);
    }
```

Now what I want to do, for every instance of my control, to take the result of the dialog and put it in the textbox that's in the control. I've been thinking of:

1. maybe a command parameter that would be sent to this OpenFileExplorer, telling which property should be updated somehow, but I am not sure how.
2. Write this command multiple times for each property. I don't think this is correct.
3. Create a new viewmodel for my control with this command and make instances of it in my current view model.

What would you guys say the best way to do this? it is relatively simple, although it got me kind of confused.